# Me duplica los resultados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Creo una tabla para mostrar los resultados de una consulta, el bucle while genera las filas mientrás hay resultados, a su vez un segundo bucle while rellena los select de categoría de cada fila. Parece que hay algún error en los bucles debido a que me esta duplicando los resultados, debido a que el select categoria cuenta con dos resultados.

¿ Alguien ve el error ? O bien otra solución.

```html
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">Idevento
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Idrecinto
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Fecha
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Entradas Disponibles
      </th>
      <th class="th-sm">Descripción
      </th>
     <th class="th-sm">Categoría
      </th>
    <th class="th-sm">Cantidad
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
                           <?php
    require_once "config.php";
    
            while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            ?>
                            
                            <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["idevento"];?></td>  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["idrecinto"];?></td>  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["fecha"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["entradas"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["descripcion"];?></td>
                                    
                                    <td><select id="categoria" name="categoria" placeholder="Categoría">
                                    <?php
                                    
                                    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM categoria ;";  
                                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
                
                                    while ($datos2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo 'Categoría '. $datos2["idcategoria"];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos2["precio"];?>" ><?php echo $datos2["idcategoria"].' ('; echo $datos2["precio"].')';?></option>
                                     
                                    <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                                         
                                    </select></td>
                                <td><input id="cantidad" min="1" max="10" name="cantidad" type="number" placeholder="Cantidad"  required /></td>
                                <td><input class="button primary small" nombre="<?php echo $datos["idevento"];?>"  id="idevento" value="Añadir"></td>
                                
                                
                               </tr>  
                            

                            <?php
                            }
            
                            
        
                          
                          ?>  
                            
                            </table>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la primera consulta y decirnos si las tablas de ambas consultas se relacionan de algún modo? Es posible que puedas obtener toda la información que requieres en una sola consulta, no en dos. Es un código mal optimizado, porque ejecutas cada vez el `SELECT * FROM categoria`, de modo que si el primer `while` tiene `N` filas, estás ejecutando ese SELECT `N` veces, y `N` puede equivaler a 1, a 1000, a 500 mil, a un millón de veces. Hay un serio problema de optimización en tu código.

Comment: Son tablas distintas

Comment: El primer while carga los resultados de una tabla, y el segundo carga el campo categoría de otra, están relacionadas las tablas, pero ahí no está el problema.

Comment: Si no tienen ninguna relación, entonces **ejecuta las consultas por separado**, no una dentro de otra. Luego **guarda los resultados en variables y lee esas variables para construir el contenido**. Al ejecutar `SELECT * FROM categoria` dentro del `while` significa que si la primera consulta arroja `N` fila, estarás ejecutando `SELECT * FROM categoria` `N` veces sin ninguna necesidad. Es pésimo a nivel de optimización. No sé si llegas a entender lo que trato de explicarte.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero como el segundo while va a tener pocos resultados, la optimización no me importa

Comment: El problema está en que parece que los while's no están bien aninados, y por eso duplica el resultado

Comment: La optimización debe importarte. Y además el problema que tienes también es por ese motivo, aparte de la optimización. Lo escribiré en una respuesta a ver si así me entiendes mejor...

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, quieres mostrar en una tabla una lista de eventos, y dentro de una de las columnas de la tabla quieres mostrar un `select` con las opciones de otra tabla `categoria`.

Estás planteando mal tu código desde el punto de vista de la organización y de la optimización.

Si, como parece, el contenido de la tabla `categoria` es **fijo**, no tiene ningún sentido consultar una y oooootra vez la tabla para obtener **los mismos resultados** en bucle. Es mejor construir esos datos fijos en una variable por ejemplo y usarla en el `<td>` que corresponda.

Por tanto, puedes organizar el código del siguiente modo:

1. Lee en primer lugar la tabla `categoria` y guarda el `select`, **puesto que es fijo**
2. Lee los datos de eventos y muestra el  select que ya construiste en (1)

El código quedaría así. Me he enfocado en el problema. Si quieres darle coherencia puedes adaptar las otras partes. Falta por ejemplo cerrar la tabla y demás cuestiones que dejo a tu cuidado. Lo importante es que entiendas la simplicidad de la lógica que se está aplicando aquí y no marees tanto el código haciéndolo pesado sin necesidad.

```
/* Primero guardamos el select con las categorías
    UNA SOLA VEZ, no todas las veces
*/
$sql ="SELECT * FROM categoria;";
#No la nombramos $result2 ... es una variable reutilizable  
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$mSelect="<select id=\"categoria\" name=\"categoria\" placeholder=\"Categoría\">";                
while ($categorie=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    #No entiendo mucho ese precio= qué hace ahí, pero bueno....
    $mSelect.="<option value=\"$categorie[idcategoria]\" precio=\"$categorie[precio]\">$categorie[idcategoria] ($categorie[precio])</option>";
}
$mSelect.="</select>";

/*
    Ahora leemos los eventos 
    y usamos el array de categrías ya guardado
    Usaremos concatenaciones para evitar 
    la confusa mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML
*/


/*
   IMPORTANTE: En el contexto de la pregunta no aparece
   dónde obtienes este segundo resultado
   debes incorporarlo aquí, luego de haber leído categoria
*/

$html="";
while ($event=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $html.="<tr>  
                <td>$event[idevento]</td>  
                <td>$event[idrecinto]</td>  
                <td>$event[fecha]</td>  
                <td>$event[entradas]</td>  
                <td>$event[descripcion]</td>
                <td>$mSelect</td>
            </tr>";
}
/*
    Imprimimos todo lo que se ha concatenado
*/
echo $html;
```